# v0.5.1 Kiln unable to initialize node Level Error

Tags: kiln

Followed the following:
https://medium.com/@obsidian.systems/how-to-install-kiln-and-bake-on-ubuntu-a13d17df63c

Kiln Node displays Initializing and does not connect

Viewed log with: journalctl -u kiln

```
LevelError""PublicNodeError_RpcError (RpcError_HttpException "HttpExceptionRequest Request {\n  host  = \"127.0.0.1\"\n  port                 = 8732\n  secure  = False\n  requestHeaders   = [(\"User-Agent\",\"tezos-bake-monitor-lib/0.1.0.0\"),(\"Accept\",\"*/*\")]\n  path  = \"/chains/NetXdQprcVkpaWU/blocks/head/context/constants\"\n  queryString          = \"\"\n  method  = \"GET\"\n  proxy  = Nothing\n  rawBody = False\n  redirectCount  = 10\n  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault\n  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1\n}\n (ConnectionFailure Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 17>: does not exist (Connection refused))")
```

Comment: Log also displays this same line many times: supervise: child terminated with Left readCreateProcess: /nix/store/db0p6haglamfi6136qjhiv464v9ccw4y-scoped-tzkits/bin/mainnet-tezos-node "config" "show" "--config-file" "/var/lib/kiln/data-dir/.tezos-node-config872-659.json" "--data-dir" "/var/lib/kiln/data-dir/tezos-node/NetXdQprcVkpaWU" (exit -4): failed; restarting

Answer (score 1):

Kiln developer here. The error you posted in the comment is actually relevant and might be the cause why your node is not working. Unfortunately it is not possible to figure out what the problem is by just looking at this log snippet. Is it possible to get more information about your system

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS installed on SSD with Intel Core i5 CPU

Comment: The error is coming from the `tezos-node` and its quite hard to tell why it is not able to run. Can you provide the output of `ls -l /var/lib/kiln/data-dir` and `ls -l /var/lib/kiln/*` commands

Comment: $ ls -l /var/lib/kiln/data-dir
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 kiln kiln 4096 Apr 26 19:33 tezos-client

Comment: /var/lib/kiln/exe-dir:
total 20
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kiln users   61 Dec 31  1969 backend -> /nix/store/7lzj7nbnyvx8i8rx0cwayknqx9xbdhdc-serverExe/backend
drwxr-xr-x 3 kiln kiln  4096 May  3 20:53 db
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kiln users   75 Dec 31  1969 frontend.jsexe.assets -> /nix/store/7lzj7nbnyvx8i8rx0cwayknqx9xbdhdc-serverExe/frontend.jsexe.assets
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kiln users   67 Dec 31  1969 static.assets -> /nix/store/7lzj7nbnyvx8i8rx0cwayknqx9xbdhdc-serverExe/static.assets
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kiln users   61 Dec 31  1969 version -> /nix/store/7lzj7nbnyvx8i8rx0cwayknqx9xbdhdc-serverExe/version

Comment: /var/lib/kiln/root-dir:
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 2 kiln users 4096 Dec 31  1969 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 kiln users 4096 Dec 31  1969 dev
drwxr-xr-x 2 kiln users 4096 Dec 31  1969 etc
drwxr-xr-x 2 kiln users 4096 Dec 31  1969 lib
drwxr-xr-x 2 kiln users 4096 Dec 31  1969 lib64
drwxr-xr-x 2 kiln users 4096 Dec 31  1969 nix
drwxr-xr-x 2 kiln kiln  4096 Apr 26 19:33 oldroot
drwxr-xr-x 2 kiln users 4096 Dec 31  1969 proc
drwxr-xr-x 2 kiln users 4096 Dec 31  1969 run
drwxr-xr-x 2 kiln users 4096 Dec 31  1969 sys
drwxr-xr-x 2 kiln users 4096 Dec 31  1969 tmp